# Auto-generate and auto-update timestamps in Eloquent

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.1

I am new to Laravel and I am working on my database migrations. For one table, I've included the `$table->timestamps()` shortcut in my table definition. To my dismay, I found that after I seeded the table, the values were `0000-00-00 00:00:00` for both `created_at` and `updated_at`.

I was thinking to change the column definitions to have `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, but then I wondered why Eloquent wasn't already doing this. I figured it must be For a Good Reason(tm). I suppose it's for compatibility with the different databases supported?

If I go ahead and change the column definitions, am I locking myself into a MySQL solution? I *really* don't want to have to remember to update the timestamps on every `CREATE` and `INSERT` ... Is there a way to get this done using Eloquent idioms?

Relevant code:

```
// migration method
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('category');
        $table->integer('sort_order')->unsigned();
        $table->index('sort_order');
    });
}

// seeder method
public function run()
{
    $data = [
          'Category 1'
        , 'Category 2'
    ];

    $sort = 0;

    foreach ( $data as $category ) {
        DB::table('categories')->insert([
            'category' => $category,
            'sort_order' => $sort++,
        ]);
    }
}

// database query
mysql> select * FROM categories;
+----+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+------------+
| id | created_at          | updated_at          | category       | sort_order |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+------------+
|  1 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | Category 1     |          0 |
|  2 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | Category 2     |          1 |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use Eloquent Entity to create your object.

Keep in mind Eloquent will search for database name depending on the class name. The class have to be in single form but eloquent will search for the plural version of it.

***If your database is not called the same as the class you have to add property*** `$table`.

```
<?php 

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model 
{
     protected $table = 'categories'; // not neccessary in this case

}
```

To create new row

```
$category = new CategoryEntity();
$category->category = 'your category';
$category->sort_order = 'your sort order';
$category->save();
```

To update your entity

```
$category = CategoryEntity::find($your_category_id);
$category->category = 'your category';
$category->sort_order = 'your sort order';
$category->update();
```

And when you are using like this the columns created_at and updated_at will be updated automatically.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to achieve it by mysql db own then your column property should be as per below-

```
ALTER TABLE mytable 
MODIFY COLUMN created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
MODIFY COLUMN modified TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Now don't include these 2 columns in your code for data insertion and modification then mysql automatically fill these columns as current_timestamp value.

If you pass any value then column will be updated with passed value.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that, if I make an Eloquent Model of my database table, then it will automagically fill in the timestamps when I use that class. +1 for RTFM :)

Answer (score 0):

I had an experience, in which I just missed to put **created_at** & **updated_at** on the model.

See example below:

```
protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'name',
        'username',
        'password',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at'
];
```